# How use seeding options in MikroOrm with nestJs?

Tags: nestjs, mikro-orm, nestjs-config

I'm using MikroOrm inside nestJs, and I added the following script inside `package.json`

```
"orm": "npx mikro-orm",
```

and these are the configurations

```
seeder: {
  path: 'src/misc/db/',
  defaultSeeder: 'DatabaseSeeder',
  glob: '!(*.d).{js,ts}',
  emit: 'ts',
  fileName: (className: string) => className,
}
```

I need to specify a specific seeder file when writing `npm run orm seeder:run --class=ClassNameSeeder` as the documentation mentioned, but I'm getting the following error

```
Unknown argument: ClassName
```

I tried also to run the following script in `package.json` and see if it'll work or not but I got the same error

```
"db:seed": "npm run mikro-orm seeder:run --class=ClassName"
```

### Note

The seeder class is inside `misc/db/` as I added it in my configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are passing the `--class` into the `npm run` instead of `mikro-orm` commands. I dont think it makes much sense to have an NPM script as `"orm": "npx mikro-orm"`, better to use `npx` directly, which won't suffer from this.

```
npx mikro-orm seeder:run --class=ClassNameSeeder
```

Alternatively, add `--` when you call npm. Or use something smarter like yarn or pnpm, which also handles this automatically.

```
npm run orm seeder:run -- --class=ClassNameSeeder
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar setup as yours, and I just run the following script:

```
npm run orm seeder:run
```

This will seed your database using the seeder file `src/misc/db/DatabaseSeeder.ts` by default.

Do you have multiple files, hence the need to add the class argument ?
If so, Martin's answer is probably the best to follow.